# Share website URL with image and description preview on LinkedIn

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I'm trying to share URL on **LinkedIn**, but it doesn't picking my website `description`, `title` and `image` .

I have tried these methods for sharing but none of these are working.

[Share Method 1](http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://ieleads.com/leads/lead/670)

[Share Method 2](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://ieleads.com/leads/lead/670&title=Custom%20title%20&summary=my%20summary%20&source=LinkedIn)

Second seems work for me but it does not pick image. What am I doing wrong here?

[**Js Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0ad8p3fh/)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn only supports one URL format...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

But if you want to populate things like `title` and `image` in the preview of the share page, then you need to use `og:` tags.  Insert these into the `<head>` block your HTML...

- `<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property="og:image" content="//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property="og:description" content="Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property="og:url" content="//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

If you're not sure, then you can always consult the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

Comment: The Post Inspector is super helpful.   LinkedIn support did not tell me about that.  I was able to solve my problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the second method you're using is right, the fact that a pic is missing is simply because there insn't an image on your page.

Let's suppose your website is www.randomurl.com and the page you want to share is www.randomurl.com/randompost.php

Your sharer href would be

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.randomurl.com/randompost.php&title=yourposttitle&source=http://www.randomurl.com
```

The sharer will pick the most significant image found on www.randomurl.com/randompost.php

EDIT: since I noticed you include your img in open graph tags, try to use og:image:secure_url instead of normal og:image:url since you're using an image behind secure connection (https)

Comment: I have image on my page . You can check it too. inside `og:image`.

Comment: I just checked and it's pretty weird... can you link the image in your og tag without https prefix but just http?

Comment: I have change the url, but it's still not picking img.

Comment: also beware of the img/type you specify in 
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
because you're linking a .png.

I'd structure the head this way
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />

omitting the image type tag if your pics are sometimes png, sometime jpg...

Comment: Unfortunately, it could literally be everything: I'd start by correcting the script errors in your code (chrome gives me some errors and warnings) and if your cms has particular plugins such as betterWPsecurity, shutting them down and trying again.

Comment: No I'm not using plugin. And which type of errors are you getting . What I need to do to correct those/

Answer (score 0):

I am tried these methods for sharing and these are working.

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.randomurl.com/randompost.php&submitted-image-url=https://yourprojectimage.png&title=yourposttitle&summary=yourprojectsummary&source=http://www.randomurl.com
```